# Convert Linq ObjectQuery IQueryable to IEnumerable

Tags: linq

Totally confused about the data types required here.

I have this Linq statement:

```
                var feat = AllCustomers
                    .Select(c => c.CustomerServices.SelectMany(cs => cs.CustomerServiceFeatures)
                    .SelectMany(csf => csf.ConfigElements).Where(ce => ce.Name == "ItemType").Select(ce => ce.Value).Distinct());
```

It returns the required data, and VS tells me that the type is being set as:

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>
```

However I want to add this data into a list of strings:

```
 List<string> itemTypes = new List<string>();
 itemTypes.AddRange(feat);
```

But this throws an error:

```
 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'
```

I can't find the required syntax to cast to correct type. Can anyone help?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compile-time error shows, that `feat` is "collection of collection of string" (literally "IQueryable of IEnumerable of string"). So you need to generate flat collection.

```
feat.SelectMany(x => x)
```

Comment: The answer was staring me right in the face this whole time, I was trying all sorts of SelectMany() tricks besides this one. Also.. this answer was very difficult to Google for!

Answer (score 1):

`System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>` is an implementation of `System.Linq.IQueryable<T>`. Your type, however, is an IQueryable of IEnumerable objects. Perform a SelectMany, so you no longer have a collection of string collections, but just a collection of strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
List<string> list = feat.ToList<string>()
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you but this does not work. You need SelectMany() to flatten the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do with the list you can just do:

```
var itemTypes = feat.ToList();
```